# angular2 formArray conditional validation

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I'm trying to impose validation based on a change of one field onto another field inside a formGroup which is inside a FormArray of multiple instances of this group. I'm using mydatepicker on one of the fields. For example, when the date is changed, I then want the Reason for change field in that group only to be validated to check to make sure the first option (value of 0) is not selected. I have 2 problems with this:

1. When I change the date, the Reason for change field does not get checked for validity right away. It only happens AFTER I change the value of the field to 1 and then to 0. It's default is set to 0 and it should immediately pick this up when I change the date.
2. When it does finally realize the form is invalid, it does it for ALL the update buttons rather than just the one in the FormGroup whose Date field I have changed.

ts file code:

```js
subscribeDateChange(formGroup){
(<any>this.rfcActionTasksForm).controls.tasks.controls[0].controls['DueDate'];
const tasks = formGroup;


const changes$ = tasks.controls['DueDate'].valueChanges;



changes$.subscribe(dd => {
  var arrayControl = this.rfcActionTasksForm.get('tasks') as FormArray;
  var item = arrayControl.at(1);
  console.log(item);
  if(tasks.value['ReasonForChangeId'] == '0'){

    tasks.controls['ReasonForChangeId'].setValidators(Validators.pattern(/([1-9])/));

  }


});
}

ngOnInit() {
this.rfcActionTasksForm = this._fb.group({
  tasks: this._fb.array([this.buildTask()])

});


}
buildTask(): FormGroup {
  return this._fb.group({
      Id: '',
      Action: ['', Validators.required],
      Step: '',
      AssignedToId: ['', Validators.required],
      AssignedToColour: '',
      DueDate: ['', Validators.required],
      ReasonForChangeId: '',
      OriginalDueDate: '',
      Completed: '',
      OverDue: ''
  },{
    validator: (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
      //return this.validateDays(formGroup);
      //console.log(formGroup.controls['DueDate']);
      //this.subscribeDateChange(formGroup.controls['DueDate'], formGroup.controls['ReasonForChangeId']);
     return this.subscribeDateChange(formGroup);
    }
    });

}
```

html:

```html
    <form class="multi-col implementation" *ngIf="rfc.Plan [formGroup]="rfcActionTasksForm">
  <div class="task-item" formArrayName="tasks" *ngFor="let task of tasks.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="row header-row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h5 class="no-margin">Step {{i + 1}}</h5>
            <input
                [style.display]="'none'"
                formControlName="Step">
            <input
                [style.display]="'none'"
                formControlName="AssignedToColour">
            <input
                [style.display]="'none'"
                formControlName="Id">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-row row">
          <div class="col-md-11">
            <label for="{{'task' + i}}">Action:</label>
              <div
                    [ngClass]="{'has-error': (tasks.get(i + '.Action').touched || tasks.get(i + '.Action').dirty) && !tasks.get(i + '.Action').valid }">
                <textarea 
                rows="6"
                id="{{'task' + i}}"
                formControlName="Action"></textarea>

                <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(tasks.get(i + '.Action').touched || tasks.get(i + '.Action').dirty) && tasks.get(i + '.Action').errors">
                      <span *ngIf="tasks.get(i + '.Action').errors.required">
                          Please enter a title.
                      </span>
                  </span>

              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <label>Status</label>
            <i *ngIf="tasks.get(i + '.Completed').value" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign ok" title="Completed"></i>
            <i *ngIf="!tasks.get(i + '.Completed').value && !tasks.get(i + '.OverDue').value" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign pending" title="In progress"></i>
            <i *ngIf="!tasks.get(i + '.Completed').value && tasks.get(i + '.OverDue').value" class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign text-danger" title="Overdue!"></i>
          </div>

      </div>
      <div class="input-row row">
        <div class="col-md-3 assigned-to">
          <div
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': (tasks.get(i + '.AssignedToId').touched || tasks.get(i + '.AssignedToId').dirty) && !tasks.get(i + '.AssignedToId').valid }">
              <label for="{{'assignedTo' + i}}">Assigned to:</label>
              <div class="color-block" [style.background]="tasks.get(i + '.AssignedToColour').value"></div>
              <label class="fa select">
                <select
                  *ngIf="users"
                  id="{{'assignedTo' + i}}"
                  formControlName="AssignedToId">
                  <option 

                    *ngFor="let user of users | trueValueFilter: 'IsActive'"
                    [value]="user.Id">{{user.Name}}</option>
                </select>
              </label>

              <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(tasks.get(i + '.AssignedToId').touched || tasks.get(i + '.AssignedToId').dirty) && tasks.get(i + '.AssignedToId').errors">
                  <span *ngIf="tasks.get(i + '.AssignedToId').errors.required">
                      Please select a user.
                  </span>
              </span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <div 
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': (tasks.get(i + '.DueDate').touched || tasks.get(i + '.DueDate').dirty) && !tasks.get(i + '.DueDate').valid }">
              <label for="{{'dueDate' + i}}">Due date:</label>
              <my-date-picker 
                  class="datepicker"
                  type="text" 
                  id="{{'dueDate' + i}}"

                  formControlName="DueDate"
                  [options]="myDatePickerOptions"></my-date-picker>

                  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(tasks.get(i + '.DueDate').touched || tasks.get(i + '.DueDate').dirty) && tasks.get(i + '.DueDate').errors">
                    <span *ngIf="tasks.get(i + '.DueDate').errors.required">
                        Please set a due date.
                    </span>
                  </span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">


            <label for="{{'reason' + i}}">Reason for change:</label>
            <label class="fa select">
              <select
                class="reason-select"
                *ngIf="reasons" 
                id="{{'reason' + i}}"
                formControlName="ReasonForChangeId">
                <option 

                  *ngFor="let reason of reasons"
                  [value]="reason.Id">{{reason.Reason}}</option>
              </select>
            </label>


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="text-center">
              <label for="{{'OriginalDueDate' + i}}">Original due date:</label>
              <span>{{tasks.get(i + '.OriginalDueDate').value  | dateToStringFilter}}</span>
              <input 
                readonly
                type="text"
                id="{{'OriginalDueDate' + i}}"
                 [style.display]="'none'"
                formControlName="OriginalDueDate">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
           <div class="text-center">
              <label for="{{'completed' + i}}">Completed:</label>

                  <div class="checkbox-group">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                      type="checkbox" 
                      id="{{'completed' + i}}"
                      formControlName="Completed">
                    <label class="checkbox" for="{{'completed' + i}}"></label>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div>

            <button 
              class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign btn-icon add" 
              title="Insert task after this one" 
              (click)="insertTaskField(i)"></button>

            <button 
              class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign btn-icon delete" 
              title="Delete this task" 
              (click)="removeTaskField(i, tasks.get(i + '.Id')?.value)"></button>

              <button 
              *ngIf="!tasks.get(i + '.Id').value"
              (click)="saveNewTask(rfc.Id, i);"
              [disabled]="!rfcActionTasksForm.valid"
              class="pull-right">Save new</button>
              <button 
               *ngIf="tasks.get(i + '.Id')?.value"
               [disabled]="!rfcActionTasksForm.valid"
               (click)="updateTask(i, tasks.get(i + '.Id')?.value)"
                class="pull-right">Update</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row last">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button 
        class="pull-right"
        [disabled]="enableUpdateAll === false"
        (click)="reOrderTasks()">Update All</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple problems here:

A validator should be of the form:

```js
(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    if(isValid(control))
      return null;
    else
      return {"myValidator":"invalid thing detected"};
 }
```

You are returning `undefined` everytime so it can't work.
You cannot subscribe because it means everytime you make a change in your form, you resubscribe to the whole group's valuechanges, that's non-sense.

Forget about valueChanges, you need to do your control synchronously. Check if there is an error and use the `setError()` method of your children controls.

something like :

```js
(group: FromGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
    if(!isValid(group)){
      group.get("myChildControl").setErrors({"localError":"error detected !"});
      return {"groupError":"error detected !"};
    }
    return null;
 }
```

I'm not sure if you should use the second parameter of `setError(errors,{emitEvent:false})` to avoid propagation or not.

Comment: Thanks. Where does this validate function need to be added exactly?

Comment: replace your arrow function `validator: (formGroup: FormGroup) => {...}` in your group when you build it.